# jQuery UI Slider being re-created when AJAX is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

I am having a strange issue (I may just be unclear how jQuery UI Slider is supposed to work).

I have the following:

```
//$.ajax is being called inside of button click
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    dataType : "json",
    url: 'url-here',
    data : {action: "search_stores"},
    beforeSend: function(){
        $('.table-block').addClass('loading');
    },
    success: function(result){
        $('.table-block').removeClass('loading');                                                       
    },
    error: function(respoonse){
        console.log(response);
    }                           
});
```

In the DOM ready:

```
$( "#slider" ).slider({
    value:5,
    min: 5,
    max: 50,
    step: 5,
    slide: function(e, ui) {        
        // radius.val(ui.value);
    }, stop: function(){
        // need to call in ajax
    }, create: function(e, ui){
        console.log("created");                                     
    }
});
```

Everytime make an ajax request (via element click) the slider resets and is created again.  I would like to retain the values for the slider when clicked.  I know how I can do this but I would like to prevent the slider from being recreated on each click.

Comment: Is the button click causing a postback? My first thought would be to try `e.preventDefault()` in your click handler.

Comment: What does `setupLocations` do?

Comment: @tymeJV I have e.prevenDefault(); and jo8691 - I have this commented out and removed from example.

Comment: Any reason for the slider being inside the click handler?

Comment: @tymeJV only the $ajax is inside click handler

Comment: Show HTML of Slider and elements around..

Comment: Can you reproduce this in jsFiddle?